# Check if object property value is unique and if not filter out - JS

Tags: javascript

I am building a small webapp and I am using this [API](https://data.nasa.gov/Management-Operations/NASA-Facilities/gvk9-iz74) which has around 485 objects in it. Those objects have specific property `center`. It can happen that the `center` property sometimes is equel (and not unique) to other object' `center`. How can I filter out the duplicates?

**My code so far**

```
function call() {

    fetch('https://data.nasa.gov/resource/9g7e-7hzz.json')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            locations = data;
            getLocations(locations);
        })

}

function getLocations(locations) {

    //Filter out duplicates and push it to an array
    locations.forEach((location) => {

        console.log(location.center);

    })



}
```

[image]

So the result I expect is an array with objects, with unique values in the `center` property. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

`Set` can help you here:

```
function getLocations(locations) {
    let centers = new Set();
    let uniques = [];
    for (let location of locations) {
        if (!centers.has(location.center)) {
            centers.add(location.center);
            uniques.push(location);
        }
    }
    return uniques;
}
```

Comment: @baao please argument

Comment: @baao Care to explain why? I'm willing to accept there's something I overlooked, but please be constructive.

Comment: @baao your response is terrible...

Comment: @baao did you delete your comment?

Comment: he did, what a nice guy, pleasure to meet such...